# Manipulate and convert a *txt in data frame object

Tags: r, dataframe, text, data-manipulation, yolo

I've like to make a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) with the results of training [yolo](/questions/tagged/yolo) `v3 model` in [r](/questions/tagged/r). But I have a very complicated output object in `*.txt`, in my example:

## Original file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pncmjwl3camap6d/log.txt?dl=0

```
myfile<-read.table("log.txt", sep="\t", quote="", comment.char="")
```

## partial structure: myfile

```
obj
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005
Resizing
416
Loaded: 0.062388 seconds
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.254732, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.575008, No Obj: 0.417811, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 4
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.496387, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.415856, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.263274, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.306391, No Obj: 0.418069, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 4
Region 94 Avg IOU: 0.435966, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.207774, No Obj: 0.496172, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 1
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.413582, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.303235, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.424457, No Obj: 0.418686, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 4
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.496352, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: 0.579218, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.502197, No Obj: 0.415232, .5R: 1.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 1
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.187162, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.501398, No Obj: 0.416089, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 5
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.496362, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.414499, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.271427, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.481964, No Obj: 0.417647, .5R: 0.166667, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 6
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.495838, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.415899, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.285605, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.469981, No Obj: 0.417026, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 3
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.494833, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.413943, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.300229, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.313481, No Obj: 0.416831, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 6
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.495936, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.413855, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.384617, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.398042, No Obj: 0.418052, .5R: 0.333333, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 3
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.496205, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 106 Avg IOU: 0.144387, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.349722, No Obj: 0.414624, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 1
1: 799.219543, 799.219543 avg, 0.000000 rate, 654.661284 seconds, 24 images
Loaded: 0.000042 seconds
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.308919, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.264983, No Obj: 0.418332, .5R: 0.250000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 4
Region 94 Avg IOU: 0.204282, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.167168, No Obj: 0.495162, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 2
Region 106 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.415848, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
Region 82 Avg IOU: 0.274081, Class: 0.000000, Obj: 0.471111, No Obj: 0.418323, .5R: 0.000000, .75R: 0.000000,  count: 3
Region 94 Avg IOU: -nan, Class: -nan, Obj: -nan, No Obj: 0.495826, .5R: -nan, .75R: -nan,  count: 0
...
```

Now I want to create a data frame, I know that each iteraction in the model start and finish with `Loaded:` expression and before
this expression I have `"1: 799.219543, 799.219543 avg, 0.000000 rate, 654.661284 seconds, 24 images"` always started with a number and `:` 
(indicates the current training iteration/batch),
but I neeed some rule (information not necessary started with `Region` and occurs every 24 lines), first for separate only this specifics training iteration/batch results like:

```
1: 799.219543, 799.219543 avg, 0.000000 rate, 654.661284 seconds, 24 images
2: 799.555359, 799.253113 avg, 0.000000 rate, 672.519735 seconds, 48 images
...
55: 1025.803833, 1181.399658 avg, 0.000000 rate, 919.132681 seconds, 1320 images
```

and after make some new manipulation for create my final data frame:

```
iteration  total_loss  loss_error  rate      time       n_images       
1          799.219543  799.219543  0.000000  654.661284 24
2          799.555359  799.253113  0.000000  672.519735 48
...
55         1025.803833 1181.399658 0.000000  919.132681  1320
```

Please, someone who has already manipulated this type of file has any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `readLines` and subset for rows beginning with a number followed by a colon using `grep`. After that do some cleaning using `strsplit` and `gsub`, convert `as.numeric` and `setNames`. Done!

```
tmp <- readLines("log.txt") 
tmp <- tmp[grep("^\\d*\\:", unlist(tmp))]
tmp <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp, ", "))
tmp <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(tmp[, 1], "\\: ")), tmp[, -1], 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, gsub, pat="\\s.+", repl="")
tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, as.numeric)
res <- setNames(tmp, c("iteration", "total_loss", "loss_error", "rate", 
                       "time", "n_images"))

head(res)
#   iteration total_loss loss_error rate     time n_images
# 1         1   799.2195   799.2195    0 654.6613       24
# 2         2   799.5554   799.2531    0 672.5197       48
# 3         3   801.0438   799.4322    0 667.1184       72
# 4         4   799.9001   799.4790    0 647.3321       96
# 5         5   801.5366   799.6848    0 660.7798      120
# 6         6   799.3589   799.6522    0 683.4424      144
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` package work too:

```
library(tidyverse)
myfile <- read_lines("log.txt")

names_col <- c("iteration", "total_loss", "loss_error", "rate", "time",
"n_images")

mydf <- myfile %>%
  str_subset("images$") %>%
  enframe(name = NULL) %>%
  separate(col = value, into = names_col, sep = "[:,]") %>%
  mutate_all(parse_number)

head(as.data.frame(mydf))
#  iteration total_loss loss_error rate     time n_images
# 1         1   799.2195   799.2195    0 654.6613       24
# 2         2   799.5554   799.2531    0 672.5197       48
# 3         3   801.0438   799.4322    0 667.1184       72
# 4         4   799.9001   799.4790    0 647.3321       96
# 5         5   801.5366   799.6848    0 660.7798      120
# 6         6   799.3589   799.6522    0 683.4424      144
```